# remove file starting with space in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, space, argument-passing

I'm trying to write a shell script to cleanup a directory by deleting files that match particular patterns. My code works with all patterns but if the file name starts with space. Although we can delete a file starting with space by `rm \ *`however if I pass this pattern to my script it won't delete files starting with space. Here is my code:

```
  for file in *;do         
    for pattern in $*; do  
      if [[ -f "$file" && "$file" == $pattern ]]; then    
       rm "$file"  
      fi 
    done   
  done
```

I also tried this simpler code, but the same problem!

```
for pattern in $*; do    
  if [[ -f $pattern ]]; then   
    rm $pattern
  fi
done
```

Could you please help me why there is a problem just with files starting with space?!

Comment: for removing files starts with space find . -type f -name " "* -exec rm {} \;

Comment: problem is with $* when we assign value to variable like a=" dsdsd" and echo $a then it will print "dsdsd" without space. While assigning value to varible space is lost.

Comment: But the problem is that I need to receive the pattern from command line. My script should be called this way:   ./dirclean.sh ~/dirname "PATERN1" "PATERN2" ...  . So I have to use a variable instead of " "*  in your suggested code. In addition, PATTERN could be anything else as well, but I noticed this problem while testing my code with files starting with space.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `$*`, if you use the [special parameter](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_02) `$@`, the items in the list will start with quotes around them.  You still have to quote the variables where you use them.

Reworking the second example, that would be

```
for pattern in "$@"; do    
  if [[ -f "$pattern" ]]; then   
    rm -f "$pattern"
  fi
done
```

Comment: I changed the code, But it doesn't delete files starting with space. My Script file name is dirclean ad I run it as follow:   ./dirclean.sh ~/mydir "\ *"  . This result in deletion of all files in mydir.

Comment: sorry - I forgot to quote $@ -- tested just now.

Comment: This time it's not working with any other patterns as well because when $@ is quoted, it would be considered as a string. This only can delete files with the name of $@

Comment: It sounds as if on applying the suggested changes, your resulting script has either single-quoted something, or escaped something.  The reworked second example was able to work as expected with a plain `*` (no quotes) for a parameter.  bash (not mentioned in the question) does have a way to match against a *pattern*.  You might want to start a new question to focus on that aspect.

Comment: "$pattern" should not be quoted since "$@" will put all arguments in a separate double quotation.

Answer (score 0):

this is really a challenging one
for starters please see below example

```
[shravan@localhost mydir]$ ls " myfile"
 myfile
[shravan@localhost mydir]$ echo $vr1
" myfile"
[shravan@localhost mydir]$ ls $vr1
ls: ": No such file or directory
ls: myfile": No such file or directory
[shravan@localhost mydir]$ vr2=" myfile"
[shravan@localhost mydir]$ echo $vr2
myfile
```

You can see above that ls " myfile" is working but it is not working after assigning this value in variable vr1 or vr2.
So we cannot do check of file if it exists or not.

For solution keep all you patterns in a file and all patterns in double quotes. see example below.

```
[shravan@localhost mydir]$ touch " myfile"
[shravan@localhost mydir]$ touch my.pl
[shravan@localhost mydir]$ ls
exe.sh  findrm  inp  input   myfile  my.pl  pattern  text  text1
[shravan@localhost mydir]$ cat inp
" myfile"
"my.pl"
[shravan@localhost mydir]$ cat inp | xargs rm
[shravan@localhost mydir]$ ls
exe.sh  findrm  inp  input  pattern  text  text1
```

The files are removed. Or if you have lot of patterns and dont want to add quotes to them use below.

```
 cat inp | awk '{print "\""$0"\""}' | xargs rm
```

Yes if file is not found then it will give error for that file that

```
rm: cannot remove ` myfile': No such file or directory
```

Comment: if you open inp file in an editor, what is stored in it? is it stored " myfile" "my.pl" or you have stored the pattern in it ex. \ * ? I stored pattern in inp file but cat doesn't convert it into file name and it brings up exactly the stored pattern.

Comment: I have stored " myfile" "my.pl"

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in *;do         
  for pattern in "$@"; do  
    if [[ -f "$file" && "$file" == $pattern ]]; then    
     rm "$file"  
     fi 
  done   
done
```

If we simply change $@ to quoted "$@" then each individual argument would be wrapped in double quotation and no space would be lost. On the other hand we need a quoted string at the right of == operator, because when the '==' operator is used inside [[ ]], the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern. But here we will not quote $pattern since all arguments in the list include double quotation.